# Why Symfony 3 can't open a _wdt/wdt url?

Tags: symfony

I have installed Symfony 3 and configure a nginx according documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html. I open the app_dev.php and Symfony sends ajax request to /_wdt, but gets 404 error.
I checked routes:

```
  Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
  _wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}
  _profiler_home             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/
  _profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search
  _profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar
  _profiler_info             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/info/{about}
  _profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
  _profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
  _profiler                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}
  _profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router
  _profiler_exception        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception
  _profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
  _twig_error_test           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}
  homepage                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
```

The _wdt route exist. Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

to verify what `{token}` you need to use, first browse to your app_dev.php URL like so. In my example my web host is "192.168.0.100":

http://192.168.0.100/app_dev.php/

In FireFox (other browsers will use different commands) right-click on the page and select "Inspect Element", then click the "Network" tab and refresh the page.

You should see something like:
GET XHR http://192.168.40.200/app_dev.php/_wdt/d8013c

Then this is the route you can enter in your browser, for example in the above example enter:

http://192.168.40.200/app_dev.php/_wdt/d8013c